# Can't call function properly in python due to unknown reasons

Tags: python-2.7

After compilation error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "python", line 29, in <module>
    File "python", line 26, in trip_cost
    TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

The following is the code for the expenditure calculation application that I wrote. There are four arguments passing inside trip_cost function in the end but four parameters defined in the function definition.

```
def hotel_cost(nights):
    return 140 * nights
def spending_money(money):
    return money
def plane_ride_cost(city):
    if city == "Charlotte":
       return 183
    elif city == "Tampa":
        return 220
    elif city == "Pittsburgh":
        return 222
    elif city == "LosAngeles":
        return 475
def rental_car_cost(days):
    cost = 40 
    if days >= 7:
        return (cost * days - 50)
    elif days >= 3 < 7:
        return (cost * days - 20)
    elif days < 3:
        return (cost * days)
def trip_cost(city,days,spending_money):
    total_trip_cost = plane_ride_cost(city) + rental_car_cost(days) + hotel_cost(days) + spending_money(spending_money)
    return total_trip_cost

print trip_cost("LosAngeles",5,600)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your local variable `spending_money` is over-writing the function `spending_money()` in your `trip_cost` function's scope.

Since the `spending_money()` function doesn't do anything, you could just add it directly.

Comment: afterwards it says: trip_cost should take exactly three parameters: city, days, and spending_money (in that order). 

its already in the same order.

Comment: what have you changed?

Comment: I have changed function name spending_money to money and agrument to spending_money. Getting 1995 as trip cost with the above error.

Answer (score 0):

```
def trip_cost(city,days,spending_money):
total_trip_cost = plane_ride_cost(city) + rental_car_cost(days) + hotel_cost(days) + spending_money(spending_money)
return total_trip_cost
```

on this part of the code, you are calling for the function **spending_money(spending_money)**, the problem is that **the variable and the function are named alike**, so python asumes that you are calling the function inside the function??? *why do humans do this to me, i feel confused, said python*.

a good tip and solution is to change the variable name or function name.

try:

```
def trip_cost(city,days,travelling_cash): 
total_trip_cost = plane_ride_cost(city) + rental_car_cost(days) +hotel_cost(days) + spending_money(travelling_cash)
return total_trip_cost
```

cheers mate!